# Get files for deployed Reports

Tags: reporting-services

Is it possible to get the files for a deployed reports ON SSRS 2005?

On of our developers deployed them to the Reporting Server, but didn't commited his changes to SVN. Now we are in an inconsistent state and we also can't find the files he created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Report Manager (usually the URL ends with /Reports or /Reports_*instanceName* ) You can look at the details of reports. The `Edit` button will allow you to download the .rdl definition files.

From
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156032(v=sql.90).aspx

> In the **Report Definition** section, click **Edit** to extract a copy of the report definition. Modifications that you make locally to the report definition are not saved on the report server.

(I should have also noted, the interface and the button name change in SSRS 2008, so these instructions are specific to SSRS 2005.)

Comment: Thanks i also found a nice tool which did a great job:http://www.sqldbatips.com/showarticle.asp?ID=62

Answer (score 0):

```
use ReportServer
go
create view vwReportDataSet_SharedDataSet_Mapping
as
select ds.itemid, ds.name as Report_DataSource,
cat.name as Shared_DataSource 
from datasets ds
inner join catalog cat on ds.linkid = cat.itemid
go
create view vwSharedDataset_Usage
as
select cat.path,
cat.name,
cat.type,
ds.Report_DataSource,
ds.Shared_DataSource
from
catalog cat
left join vwReportDataSet_SharedDataSet_Mapping ds
on cat.itemid = ds.itemid
```

**This SQL gives you your report dataset usage.**

```
select * from vwSharedDataset_Usage
where type = 2
and path like '/SIT/%'
and name in ('Report1','Report2')
```